# EF 4.0, What is ExecuteStoreQuery, What should i use i newer versions of EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I just upgraded to from EF 4.0 to 6.1. And i noticed that the project iam working on is using ExecuteStoreQuery on a few places and its not supported in EF 6.1. The problem is that i dont fully understand whats going on with it.
And Iam even more clueless about what Iam supposed to use instead.

So here is an example:

```
var query = DBContext.ExecuteStoreQuery<sy1>("select * from sy1", "sy1", MergeOption.PreserveChanges).AsQueryable().FirstOrDefault();
```

Is there a easy fix to make this opperate in newer versions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ExecuteStoreQuery` is part of the `ObjectContext`. `DbContext` was added as part of Entity Framework 4.1 and just wraps `ObjectContext` so you can drop down to it as follows:

`(myContext as IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext;`

You could then carry on and use your existing `ExecuteStoreQuery` calls as before (which would be your easy fix).

Alternatively (and perhaps more cleanly) you could use the native `SqlQuery` method on the `DbContext` ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database.sqlquery(v=vs.113).aspx )

E.g. something like this:

```
var query = myContext.Database.SqlQuery<sy1>("select * from sy1").FirstOrDefault();
```

One thing to note is that queries executed through `SqlQuery` from the `Database` are **not tracked**. Not sure if this is the case with `ExecuteStoreQuery` but potentially something to be aware of. If you need tracking you will need to use the equivalent `SqlQuery` method on the `DbSet`.